# Solace semp-rpc-soltr-jaxb-bindings.xsd file

Tags: jaxb, solace, solace-mq

I am looking for the **semp-rpc-soltr-jaxb-bindings.xsd** file which should be used while generating the java object for SEMP request.

The solace version used is 7.2.1.

`xjc -p SolaceSempRequest semp-rpc-soltr.xsd -b semp-rpc-soltr-jaxb-bindings.xsd`

Comment: The version is soltr/7_1_1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SolOS 7.1.1 does not have a JAXB bindings file.
This is a new feature only for Solace physical appliances running SolOS 7.2 onwards.

Solace Virtual Message routers also do not currently have a JAXB bindings file, but will be included in the next release.

Comment: Bindings file for VMRs are now available for download over at http://dev.solace.com/downloads/